Existence of an orthogonal matrix $Q\in O(n)$ such that $f(A) = QAQ^T$ where $A\in Sym(n)$
Let $Sym(n)$ be the set of all $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices. Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be an invertible linear map that preserves the Frobenius inner product. Suppose $T(A) \in Sym(n)$ for all $A\in Sym(n)$.
Then does there exist an orthogonal matrix $Q\in O(n)$ such that $f(A) = QAQ^T$ for all $A\in Sym(n)$?
Given the preservation of the Frobenius inner product, $T$ is an orthogonal transformation on the space of $n\times n$ real matrices. I also know that $O(n)$ acts on $Sym(n)$ by conjugation, but it doesn't seem like an orthogonal transformation that preserves symmetric matrices necessarily has an orthogonal transformation in $O(n)$ that acts on $Sym(n)$ by conjugation.

Observation: the map $T(A) = -A$ preserves symmetry and inner products, but $-A$ is not conjugate to $A$ in general.

Given any orthonormal (wrt the Frobenius inner product) basis of the space of symmetric matrices, $T$ can permute the basis, but this is not necessarily a conjugation, a sign change or a combination of those
